# How to run Python/Django combined with Apache

Tags: php, python, django, apache

I have a running apache/PHP site using XAMPP on my locahost, and i am learning the basics of python/django and have a `python manage.py runserver` on port 8000, i read about configuring the virtual host on xampp `http-vhost.conf` but cannot make it work, i just need to run both and somehow remove the port number on my python site, don't know if configuring `apache` is the best way any advice would be great!

My apache site is running using below url.

`http://localhost/myPHPwebiste`

My python/django site is running using below url.

`http://localhost:8000/myPythonwebiste`

My http-vhost.conf on apache server (i saved my python files inside the htdocs)

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8000>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/myPythonwebiste"

    <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/myPythonwebiste">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My goal is to make my python site run on url below.

`http://localhost/myPythonwebiste`

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution from apache documentation closed to what i want to achieve i include below line into my apache http.conf and got it working.

`ProxyPass /myPythonwebiste http://localhost:8000/myPythonwebiste`